# Trouble importing packages: Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have trouble importing the package Data.List in a Haskell file. the code goes like this:

```
import Data.List

module Main where
```

After this, rest of the code follows. 
I am writing the code using emacs on a Linux machine, and then using ghc command to run the file. When I compile the file, the error goes like this:

> parse error on input 'module'

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

The `module` declaration must be the first in the source file, so just swap these two lines.

Comment: I swapped the two lines as you said, but now I get the error
   Not in scope "isNumber"
as I am checking for a variable to be number.